# How to add column to dataframe so it be first column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
col1   col2  col3
1       4     5
5       8     22
0       4     9
```

I want to add new column, so it is first:

```
type    col1   col2  col3
"mean"   1       4     5
"sum"    5       8     22
"std"    0       4     9
```

how could i do that? i need to do that preferrably as short as possible

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DataFrame.insert` like so:

```
new_data = ["mean", "sum", "std"]
df.insert(0, "type", new_data)
```

```
   type  col1  col2  col3
0  mean     1     4     5
1   sum     5     8    22
2   std     0     4     9
```

The method signature for this method is as follows:

> DataFrame.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=False)